# How do i get the CheckBox in a recyclerView to work corectly?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-checkbox

I have a recyclerView with a bunch of items that have a checkbox to note there availability. Once the Checkbox is selected, the item should appear in the recycler, and this is done by updating the db. This format works for some items especially those at the end of the recycler and it fails for the others. How can I fix this?

```
 public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ItemHolder> {
private TextView viewName, viewPrice, viewStock;
private CheckBox viewAvailability;

private Context context;
private List<Item> listItems;

private DBHelper db;
@NonNull
@Override
public ItemAdapter.ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    return new ItemAdapter.ItemHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemAdapter.ItemHolder holder, int position) {
    Item item = listItems.get(position);
    holder.setDetails(item);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listItems.size();
}


public class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ItemHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        viewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewName);
        viewPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewPrice);
        viewStock = itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewStock);
        viewAvailability = itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewAvailability);
    }

    public void setDetails(final Item item) {
        db = new DBHelper(context);
        viewName.setText(item.getName());
        viewPrice.setText(item.getPrice());
        viewStock.setText(String.valueOf(item.getStock()));
        int as = item.getAvailabilityStatus();

        if (as == 1) {
            viewAvailability.setChecked(true);
        } else {
        }

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(item.getId()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
                dataBundle.putInt("id",item.getId());
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,NewItemActivity.class);
                intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        viewAvailability.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                if (viewAvailability.isChecked()){
                    //Toast.makeText(context, item.getId() + "is checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //db.updateItem(new Item(item.getName(),item.getPrice(),1,0));
                   // db.updateItem(item.getId(),item.getName(),item.getPrice(),1,0);
                    changeAvailabilty(item.getId(),item.getName(),item.getPrice(),1,1,0);
                } else {
                   // db.updateItem(new Item(item.getName(),item.getPrice(),0,0));
                   // db.updateItem(item.getId(),item.getName(),item.getPrice(),0,0);
                    changeAvailabilty(item.getId(),item.getName(),item.getPrice(),1,0,0);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

public ItemAdapter(Context context, List<Item> objects) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listItems = objects;
}

public void changeAvailabilty(int id, String name, String price, int stock, int av, int st) {
    if (av == 1){
        db.updateItem(id,name,price, stock,av,st);
        Toast.makeText(context, "is checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        db.updateItem(id,name,price, stock,av,st);
        Toast.makeText(context, "is not checked", 

Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if (as == 1) {
            viewAvailability.setChecked(true);
        } else {
 viewAvailability.setChecked(false);
        }

Comment: add setChecked(false) in else

Comment: But its already there, can you please be more clear

Comment: create boolean isSelected in your POJO, in your Adapter set checkBox selection based on this boolean.

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround with that.

The problem with checkbox and recyclerview combined that when you scroll the recyclerview, the holder gets destroyed and so is the viewholders state, so if you want to store the view state you have to store it in either viewholder or the data which recyclerview is displaying.

Like you are displaying item

```
private List<Item> listItems;
```

In the list items class include the Boolean is checked and by default make it `false`.

Whenever you check the box write

```
listitems.checkboxstate=false;
```

When you are changing the checkbox state make it `true`

```
listitems.checkboxstate=true;
```

but before doing that you have to make sure that checkbox is previously checked or not

```
if(listitems.checkboxstate){checkbox.setchecked(true)}
else{checkbox.setchacked(false)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `setOnCheckedChangeListener` of `viewAvailability` set `AvailabilityStatus` to `1` when user checked the `chckbox` otherwise set it `0`. like following.

```
viewAvailability.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                if (viewAvailability.isChecked()){
                    //Toast.makeText(context, item.getId() + "is checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //db.updateItem(new Item(item.getName(),item.getPrice(),1,0));
                   // db.updateItem(item.getId(),item.getName(),item.getPrice(),1,0);
                    changeAvailabilty(item.getId(),item.getName(),item.getPrice(),1,1,0);
                  
                   // here you have to set Availability Status is 1
                   item.setAvailabilityStatus(1)
                } else {
                   // db.updateItem(new Item(item.getName(),item.getPrice(),0,0));
                   // db.updateItem(item.getId(),item.getName(),item.getPrice(),0,0);
                    changeAvailabilty(item.getId(),item.getName(),item.getPrice(),1,0,0);

                   // here you have to set Availability Status is 0
                   item.setAvailabilityStatus(0)
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

**UPDATE**

In your `Item` model class add an extra property named `isSelected` with `getter` and `setter` like

```
public class Item{
    // your other properties

    private boolean isSelected;

    public boolean getSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }
 
    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        isSelected = selected;
    }
}
```

And in your adapter, you have to set `isSelected` is `true` if user checked the `chekcbox` otherwise set it as `false` inside your `setDetails()`. like following.

```
public void setDetails(final Item item) {
        db = new DBHelper(context);
        viewName.setText(item.getName());
        viewPrice.setText(item.getPrice());
        viewStock.setText(String.valueOf(item.getStock()));
        int as = item.getAvailabilityStatus();
        
        // Here you should check if it is already checked or not
        if (item.getSelected) {
            viewAvailability.setChecked(true);
        } 

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(item.getId()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
                dataBundle.putInt("id",item.getId());
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,NewItemActivity.class);
                intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        viewAvailability.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                if (viewAvailability.isChecked()){
                    //Toast.makeText(context, item.getId() + "is checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //db.updateItem(new Item(item.getName(),item.getPrice(),1,0));
                   // db.updateItem(item.getId(),item.getName(),item.getPrice(),1,0);
                    changeAvailabilty(item.getId(),item.getName(),item.getPrice(),1,1,0);
                  
                   // here you have to set selected true
                   item.setSelected(true)
                } else {
                   // db.updateItem(new Item(item.getName(),item.getPrice(),0,0));
                   // db.updateItem(item.getId(),item.getName(),item.getPrice(),0,0);
                    changeAvailabilty(item.getId(),item.getName(),item.getPrice(),1,0,0);

                   // here you have to set selected false
                   item.setSelected(false)
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Override these methods in your `ItemAdapter`

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position; // return position
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position; // return position
}
```

These methods helps `recyclerView` to identify items uniquely thus it will fix your checkbox issue.